# Int Array Django passed through context to JS not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have an '`int Array`' e.g. `format [0,3,5,4,6]`, I have passed this through context. Now in my `HTML` page I have my `JavaScript/JQuery`... I thought it'd be as simple doing `{% for i in array %} i {% endfor %}` but this doesn't seem to be working for me to access the values from a loop. Can you pass a context to JavaScript from Django? how can I get around this problem?

edit the passing shouldn't be a problem if I access an index of the array by creating a variable in my view and passing that -> this will output fine in the script by simply doing `{{contextgivenname}}`

edit2: if i do `{{arrayname}}` it will return the first value. But only the first value. So the only way to return all is to loop through it; which isn't working.

```
anArray2 = [int(i['age']) for i in anArray]
{
'anArray2':anArray2
}
```

In JavaScript/Jquery when I'm trying to grab the data and use it {{anArray2}} = first value in it.. but if I loop via as mentioned above then nothing.

Comment: post your code, as you should be able to pass a list to the context and do the for loop as indicated. another option is to use json.dumps(array_var) into the context, then do `{{ array_var_context|safe }}`

Comment: done - May I add that I'm trying to add the data into a chart thing but that shouldn't matter cause when I just do {{array}} in it, the first value will be put into the chart.. but no values will be if I try loop through them

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do in your anArray2 assignment, but so long as its a proper array, in the template `{% for i in anArray2 %}i{% endfor%}` should work, although won't be proper javascript array. better to use json.dumps in your view context.

Comment: convert the previous array to an int array and only grabbing one thing rather than the other crap the other array was returning from the db

Comment: are you sure that its returning a multi value array?

Comment: @warath-coder yeh because when I do {{anArray}} in the html page ( not javaScript ) it display multiple values like [0,1,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

best way to get javascript usable variables would be to do this in your view.

```
array_var = [1, 2, 44, 323]

return render(request, 'template.html', { 'arrayList': json.dumps(array_var) })
```

then in the template.

```
<script>
  var arrayList = {{arrayList|safe}};
  //... you js script
</script>
```

Comment: would you access the values via a javascript forloop or django forloop on the 'arrayList' ?

Comment: its now in your template in javascript, so you would pass this array to your chart program, or do whatever you want with it in javascript.